# What does a web developer use to debug CSP?

Tags: php, http, https, content-security-policy

Using the HTTP header, I set the CSP of that one page like so:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src https://www.example.com
```

Then firefox tries to load the favicon.ico and gets this error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.example.com/favicon.ico (“default-src”).

Is there a way in Firefox to know how it came to this conclusion? (i.e. a way to trace the CSP processing for a page).

**Note 1:** The `favicon.ico` request never makes it to the server.

**Note 2:** The page I am testing is a .php script which at first was in the root folder (`/my-script.php`). The issue with the `favicon.ico` file started when I moved that script in a sub-folder (`/sub-folder/my-script.php`). The script returns a JSON file (not HTML). I do not seem to have such an issue with HTML pages, some of which also appear under sub-folders.

Comment: It seems the issue is the json viewer : https://quabr.com/69819430/favicon-ico-blocked-by-csp-when-fetching-json-on-firefox

Comment: @JoelCrypto "Great!" That means it's not just me going crazy... :-)